# Convert below string to NSArray

Tags: ios, swift2

Actually i am getting this data from remote file

http://appsnurture.com/csv/sample.csv

```
"\"030506941\"\n\"032752389\"\n\"033415694\"\n\"035010096\"\‌​n\"035010106\"\n\"03‌​5010108\"\n\"0350101‌​18\"\n

if let url = NSURL(string: "http://appsnurture.com/csv/sample.csv") {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            let resstr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print(resstr)
        }
```

How i can parse above string to array without quote mark.
I am open for another option for parsing CSV from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try something like

```
var str = "your string"
var newString =  str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
var newString2 =  newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: " ")
var arrayWithoutQOutes = newString2.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
```

Comment: i think there is a line break too

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Why would you replace the linebreaks by spaces then break on spaces instead of just breaking on linebreaks? ;)

Comment: yes he could do it bu his first question contains spaces thats why i changed line breaks too to spces and then  splitting it to array

Comment: Thanks i understood my mistake with.up voted and approved.there was issue with \n

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I understand that, what I meant is that we don't care about the history of the question now that OP has finally edited it correctly; what's important is to give a good, optimal answer. My comment was just telling you that you could do less operations for the same result. :)